# How to manipulate integer data in CSV?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to make a bank , but i am failing to change the integer data of the file.
What my file contains is:

```
astle,hello,11

monish,mr7,0
```

Now in my 'choice1'(later show in the code) when i try to deposit say suppose 100 , it does not change the value instead gives the same value.Like in this case if i enter my username as 'astle' and try to deposit 100 , the value becomes 100 and not 111.I want 111 as when you deposit it should be old value + newvalue.
I have tried the following code but of no avail.

This is my code:

```
import csv
run=True
while run==True:
    print "1) Deposit money"
    choice=input("Enter your choice over here: ")
    #This part takes the input from the user and then stores it in 'store.txt'
    if choice==1:
        b=raw_input("Enter the username: " )
        with open('store.txt','r') as f:
            reader = list(csv.reader(f))
            for row in reader:
                if b==row[0]: #Check the username with the file
                    c=input("Enter your new ammount")
                    print row[2],"Old value"
                    a=int(row[2])
                    print a
                    row[2] = c
                    print row[2],"New value"
                    flag = 1 
                    break
                else:
                    flag=0
        if flag==0:
            print "Username does not exist."

        #Writes the new value in the file
        with open('store.txt','w') as f:
            wr = csv.writer(f)
            for row in reader:
                wr.writerow(row)
```

I have tried replacing row[2] = c with row[2] += c but it gives me the following error:

```
 row[2]+=d
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Comment: Just replace `row[2] = c` with `row[2] += c`. But except for academic purposes, a CSV file is **not** the right tool here ;-)

Comment: I don't see `old value + newvalue` operation in your code

Comment: @SergeBallesta I have already tried that but it gives me this error.  
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects.

Comment: Have you tried this: `row[2] = int(row[2]) + d`

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE , thanks i got the solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the value from `str` to `int`. Try this.

```
row[2] = str(int(row[2]) + c)
```

Comment: @KrutPatel Happy to help. Please mark as the answer it works for you. :)